Minimally clued 2x3 Sudoku
Beginner puzzleThis puzzle is intended to be suitable for people who are new to puzzle solving. However, both experienced solvers and new solvers are welcome to post solutions to this puzzle.

Objective:

Fill in the 6x6 grid with digits such that each row, column, and 6 2x3 subgrids that compose the grid contains the digits 1-6.


Attribution: Me

Here is the completed grid:

 

Solution path is pretty straightforward:

 Starting off with this deduction in column 3.
 
 Straight forward deductions following from this leads to this state of affairs
 


 Then with one inference chain of R1C3 being 5.
 
 It leads to this unsolvable grid (row 5 contains two 3s).


 Then we just have to put 2 in R1C3 and the rest is pretty easy to solve from there.
 

